# how to get mailbox in my server with php source

Tags: php, webmail

I try this source :

```
imap_open( "{" . $mailserver . ":" . $port . "}INBOX", $user, $pass );
```

but is Error, I dont know why? please help me.
error

```
Can't connect: Certificate failure for mail.xxxxxxxx.com: self signed certificate: /C=US/ST=Unknown/L=Unknown/O=Unknown/OU=Unknown/CN=terra.duoserversindonesia.com/emailAddress=ssl@terra.duoserversindonesia.com
```

Comment: What error do you get? (Wow, 5 seconds difference!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
imap_open( "{" . $mailserver . ":" . $port . "/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $user, $pass );
```

Have a look at the flags listed here for more help: http://www.php.net/imap_open